# Running my generated .jar yields "Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a AMD 64-bit platform"

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, dll, cpu-architecture

I have a project which is using some native libraries (.dll). I'm using Netbeans, and I've specified java.library.path in the run configuration. Running the project from Netbeans yields no errors.

I'm using Maven, and when building the project my jar is built in the `target` folder. I'm copying all the .dlls and my program's dependencies to `target/lib` with maven resources and dependency plugins.

When I try to run my application "outside" of Netbeans, I get the following error:

```
Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

This is the command I use to run the .jar:

```
java -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar abcontrol-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This is the command (I think) Netbeans uses to run the project from the IDE:

```
cd C:\Users\Birger\Workspace\myproject; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_77" cmd /c "\"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Dexec.args=\"-Djava.library.path=lib\\ -classpath %classpath com.mysite.myproject.Main\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_77\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 8.1\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
```

I was thinking maybe the `java` command uses a different java version than Netbeans, so I tried:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe" -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar abcontrol-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But still, I get the same error.

How can I run my application without Netbeans?

**EDIT**

From the answer provided to this question: [How can I tell if I'm running in 64-bit JVM or 32-bit JVM (from within a program)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program), I added

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
```

To my code to try to get the JVM architecture printed. I ran the application from Netbeans and "outside" netbeans, and in both cases it printed `64`.

**EDIT2**

Running `java -version` prints

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT3**

I tried to create another project using the same dependencies and libraries. This time I did NOT use maven, and in this project I get the same errors when I try to run the project:

`Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a AMD 64-bit platform`

Clearly, maven is doing some magic to get this project to run.

**EDIT4** (getting deseprate)

Tried running these two commands

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\bin\java.exe" -d32 -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar abcontrol-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" -d32 -Djava.library.path=lib\ -jar abcontrol-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Both yields

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM. Please install the desired version.
```

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit or a 64-bit JVM? The bitness of your JVM and native library must match. A 32-bit JVM cannot load a 64-bit DLL and vice versa.

Comment: I am 99% sure that I'm using 64-bit JVM. But how can I verify this? Also, I guess Netbeans uses the same JVM? If that's the case, how can Netbeans make it work while I can't?

Comment: Send dll location as parameter or check with the new File("myDllLocation").exist(); to validate before than you load system library

Comment: Oh my bad please ignore it can see the file

Comment: Running `java -version` on the command line should say something like "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM" if it's a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: I had an update installed, I removed it just to be sure but I still get the same error. Added `java -version` output to my question

Comment: @Jesper My third edit should be quite relevant, Maven in Netbeans is doing something to specify the right architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same problem when I tried to run the JAR that was built by Maven (but with a 32 bit DLL - `Can't load this .dll (machine code=0xbd) on a IA 32-bit platform`). 
Strange thing was: It happened after I moved the DLL in a folder with other resources which have to be copied during the build.

I took me a quite a while to find out that the maven resources plugin was changing the DLL file for some reason (might be a bug?). The original DLL file is 76 kb - the copied DLL in the target folder was 118 kb. Something happened to the file during build.

Adding an extra execution to copy the DLL files without `<filtering>true</filtering>` solved the problem.

Comment: It's very good. Thanks to you, I was able to save time.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative solution is to use what was suggested in the following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24282250/9293631
Which basically is to add a project level configuration so maven ignores the binary extension while filtering resources:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
      ...
      <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>swf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```