# Merging two pdf documents with PDFMergerUtility throws: IOException("Page tree root must be a dictionary")

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, pdfbox

I have a spring boot application and I am trying to merge two pdf files. The one I am getting as a byte array from another service and the one I have it locally in my resources file: /static/documents/my-file.pdf. This is the code of how I am getting byte array from my file from resources:

```
public static byte[] getMyPdfContentForLocale(final Locale locale) {
    byte[] result = new byte[0];
    try {
        final File myFile = new ClassPathResource(TEMPLATES.get(locale)).getFile();
        final Path filePath = Paths.get(myFile.getPath());
        result = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(format("Failed to get document for local %s", locale), e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting the file and getting the byte array. Later I am trying to merge this two files with the following code:

```
PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
pdfMergerUtility.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(offerDocument));
pdfMergerUtility.addSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(merkblattDocument));
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
pdfMergerUtility.setDestinationStream(os);
pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(null);
os.toByteArray();
```

But unfortunately it throws an error:

```
throw new IOException("Page tree root must be a dictionary");
```

I have checked and it makes this validation before it throws it:

```
if (!(root.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PAGES) instanceof COSDictionary))
    {
        throw new IOException("Page tree root must be a dictionary");
    }
```

And I really have no idea what does this mean and how to fix it.
The strangest thing is that I have created totally new project and tried the same code to merge two documents (the same documents) and it works!

Additionally what I have tried is:

1. Change the spring boot version if it is ok
2. Set the mergeDocuments method like this: pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(setupMainMemoryOnly())
3. Set the mergeDocuments method like this: pdfMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(setupTempFileOnly())
4. Get the bytes with a different method not using the Files from java.nio:
5. And also executed this in a different thread
6. Merging files only locally stored (in resources)
7. Merging the file that I am getting from another service - this works btw and that is why I am sure he is ok

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Please make sure you're using the latest PDFBox version (2.0.19) and share your file. Also make sure that resource filtering is disabled (this is a common pitfall!). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722595/

Comment: Why would the resource filtering be causing issues? I am actually using that to put data in some other xml files that I have.

Comment: Ok you are totally right about this filtering. But unfortunately I can't disable it. Is there any other way to avoid this in my java code?

Comment: What I was thinking about was to enable it selectively.

Comment: How to do that selectively?

Comment: That is mentioned in the links from my first comment, e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24282250/535646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as [Tilman Hausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) said is in that resource filtering that you can find in your pom file. If you have a case where you are not allowed to modify this then this approach will help you:

```
final String path = new 
ClassPathResource(TEMPLATES.get(locale)).getFile().getAbsolutePath();
final File file = new File(path);
final Path filePath = Paths.get(file.getPath());
result = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
```

and then just pass the bytes to the pdfMergerUtility object (or even the whole file instead of the list of bytes).

Comment: Don't know if this approach will work in production when it is a jar outside of your IDE.

Comment: You were right @TilmanHausherr. You shouldn't use file for location.